# ould not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium how can i solve this issue?

Tags: python, python-requests

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium

Comment: Hi Ankit. People would need a lot more detail about what environment you're using this on and the rest of your setup to be able to answer this. You also need to have a careful, systematic go at solving it yourself, and share what you investigated in a clear, organized way. See advice on [asking a good question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).